# Как изменить размер шрифта в CardView

Tags: android, recyclerview, cardview

Есть RecyclerView, в нем есть CardView, который содержит TextView. Все заполняется в адаптере. Все работает.

В активити я из диалога получаю размер шрифта и хочу, что бы после этого TextView в CardView выводились уже этим размером шрифта. Но выводится все тем размером, что задан при создании.

Как это реализовать изменение размера шрифта в процессе выполнения приложения?

---

В PostAdapter:

```
private int mFontSize;

...

public void setFontSize(int fontSize) {
    mFontSize = fontSize;

}

public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder{
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_post, parent, false);
    TextView tvpost = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.postitem_post);
    tvpost.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, mFontSize);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, tvpost.getLineHeight() * LINE_COUNT_FOR_SHORT_VIEW);

    tvpost.setLayoutParams(lp);

    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    PostModel post = posts.get(position);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        holder.post.setText(Html.fromHtml(post.getElementPureHtml(), Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
    } else {
        holder.post.setText(Html.fromHtml(post.getElementPureHtml()));
    }

    holder.post.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, mFontSize);
    ...
```

В MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    PostAdapter adapter = new PostAdapter(this, mPosts, mFontSize);
    mRvPosts.setAdapter(adapter);
    ...
}

//Сюда возвращаемся после выхода из настроек
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    // читаем размер шрифта из ListPreference
    mFontSize = Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString(getString(R.string.pref_font_size), "18"));

    PostAdapter pa = (PostAdapter) mRvPosts.getAdapter();
    pa.setFontSize(mFontSize);        

    mRvPosts.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

При перезагрузке приложения срабатывает, размер шрифта меняется, а при изменении в настройках и в работающем приложении нет...

Comment: Код в студию...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерный порядок действий такой -

1. Записывайте размер шрифта в `SharedPreferences`
2. В `onBindViewHolder` назначайте текстовому полю размер шрифта с использованием записанного ранее значения из `SharedPreferences`
3. Где-то (активити/фрагмент) регистрируйте слушатель изменения `SharedPreferences`. В нём вызывайте перерисовку адаптера вызовом `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Не работатет так...

Comment: @xsid "не работает" - мало информативно. У "не работает" всегда есть причина. Например ошибка показанная в логах, или ошибка компиляции. Может даже просто метод не вызван. Или вызван не там, не тогда или не так. В любом случае - зачем тогда отмечать ответ "верным"?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Не знаю что и где изменилось, но когда начал читать  значение размера шрифта непосредственно из настроек SharedPreferences (пункт 2), то все заработало. Поэтому и пометил ответ как решенный. До этого читал размер шрифта из настроек 1 раз, и пытался устанавливать размер из этой переменной.